# Will Gitlab trigger all jobs that listen on a branch change when I run pipeline manually

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a pipeline that contains several jobs triggered by changes on a branch:

```
deployDev:
  only:
    - dev
  script:
    - ...

deployProd:
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - ...
```

If I now hit the "Run pipeline" button in the GitLab UI, will it trigger these jobs or will it only trigger the jobs that specify `when:manual` ?

And how can I make sure that `deployDev` and `deployProd` do not run when I run a manual deploy?

I have checked here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 1):

It'll run all jobs corresponding to the branch and will wait for manual action for manual jobs.

So your deploydev will run against your development pipeline and other job will run only in production pipeline

Comment: How can I avoid running deployDev and deployProd when running manually?

Comment: It'll not run automatically you can skip it by not triggering but it'll still be in the pipeline

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused what you are trying to achieve from your comment as well,  however...

> If I now hit the "Run pipeline" button in the GitLab UI, will it trigger these jobs or will it only trigger the jobs that specify when:manual ?

As @Prashanna has said, `It'll run all jobs corresponding to the branch and will wait for manual action for manual jobs.`

If you do not want `deployDev` and `deployProd` to appear in the Pipeline when pressing the `Run Pipeline` button, you can use:

```
  only:
    - master
  except:
    - web
```

from the link you showed https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic: `web` -

> For pipelines created by using Run pipeline button in the GitLab UI, from the project’s CI/CD > Pipelines section.

The above job would then only appear in the Pipeline, when it is the `master` branch, and when it has not been triggered by the `Run Pipeline` button.